# Заголовок основного повествования

Tags: выбор-слов

Каким образом можно озаглавить начало основного повествования, когда закончился пролог?
Перевожу титры к английскому немому кино. Там есть титр "Prologue", затем следует "The Story", и в конце "Epilogue". Т.е. после событий пролога следует основная часть, и заканчивается всё эпилогом. "The Story" -- это "история" или "рассказ", если переводить на русский, но для заголовка звучит не очень. В литературе часто встречал заглавия "Пролог" и "Эпилог", но не могу припомнить заглавия для самого повествования. Есть ли какое-то общеупотребительное слово?

P.S. Я в курсе, что есть экспозиция и прочее, но так никто не озаглавливает текст, это всё термины для литературоведов.

Comment: пролог и эпилог так и пишут, а стори можно оставить "стори". То что так не пишут, не значит, что так не надо писать. К тому же кроме кинокритиков и кинофагов никто немое кино не будет смотреть.

Comment: @Буратино Нет такого русского слова "стори". Эпилог и пролог -- устоявшиеся термины, внесённые в словари. А калька с иностранного -- это зачастую свидетельство беспомощности переводчика.

Comment: начало, повесть/повествование, заключение. ранее, происшествие, итог.

Comment: "История" в качестве заголовка звучит лишним. А вот "История..." вполне нормально.